# "half the people" or "half of the people"

Tags: prepositions

*…"Prince Prospero was happy and dauntless and sagacious" even though that **half the people** in his kingdom had been killed by the Red Death.*

https://www.jstor.org/stable/3197091?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Don't you think that after "half" should follow the preposition "of" as in the sentence  "At least half of those books can be sold".

Comment: reference, please...

Comment: omitting the **of** is not unusual.... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+the+time%2C+half+of+the+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalf%20of%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JavaLatte: You can certainly omit ***of*** after ***half*** or ***all*** (and probably others that don't come to mind). But not with other "quantifiers", such as ***none, many, most,*** or with fractions preceded by the indefinite article - ***a** half, **a** quarter*, etc.